# External Hard Drive not recognized after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk

I have a WD My Book 4TB external hard drive that I have all of my photo/video content on.  It was working fine with Mavericks, but when I upgraded to El Capitan, the drive is no longer showing up on my computer.

When I boot into windows, I can see the device, and all of my content is still there... but when I go back to El Capitan, it doesn't show up in finder.

This is what I see when I use the diskutil commands from terminal.

[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that 10.11 does not recognise the MBR/FDisk_partition on your external drive. Look into 'GPT fdisk' to eventually convert the HD (don't forget a Backup). do you have to have the HD be readable/writable on both OS?

Comment: Disk2s1 is ntfs i think, so you wouldn't be able to write to it on os x without additional software

Comment: It worked perfectly fine before El Capitan.  Is it possible that Mavericks supported NTFS and El Capitan doesn't?  When I was upgrading to El Capitan, I had an upgrade issue so I booted to Windows 7, then copied all the files from my boot drive to the external to back it up.  Could that have cause the file system to switch to NtFS?